# Error: the conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to enter data into my SQL Server 2008 using data from a form. I am using a DateTimePicker to select dates from a form and enters this data to the db, however when I try to run the form I'm getting the following error:

> *The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
>
>   The statement has been terminated*

This is the code for my form below:

```
private void btnAddBooking_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            DateTime requested = dtpRequested.Value;
            DateTime pickup = dtpPickup.Value;
            DateTime estDropoff = dtpEstimatedDrop.Value;

            SAF.AddNewBooking(requested, pickup, estDropoff, selectedStatus.StatusId, selectedRate.RateId);
            dtpRequested.CustomFormat = " ";
            dtpPickup.CustomFormat = " ";
            dtpEstimatedDrop.CustomFormat = " ";

            cbStatus.SelectedIndex = 0;
            cbRateOfPayment.SelectedIndex = 0;

            MessageBox.Show("Booking Created");
            tabControl2.SelectTab(2);
}
```

Here is code in the facade where I store the method:

```
public void AddNewBooking(DateTime requestedD, DateTime pickupD, DateTime estDropOff, int statusId, int rateId)
{
            dao.AddNewBooking(requestedD, pickupD, estDropOff, statusId, rateId);
}//end CreateBooking
```

and this is the `INSERT` statement code in my DAO:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO [Transaction] (TransactionId, RequestedDateOfPickup, ActualDateOfPickup, EstimatedDropOffDate, StatusId, RateId)";
sql += String.Format("VALUES('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', {4}, {5})", transactionId, requestedD, pickupD, estDropOff, statusId, rateId);

cn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.UKRENTALSConnectionString);
cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);

cn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Use [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) ,will save you from SQL Injection and it might solve your error as well.

Comment: It was all going *so* well, until you decided to throw away the data types and treat everything as a string. As @Habib mentions, you ought to use parameters. Also, `Transaction` is a really poor name for a table (as would any other keyword be)

Answer (score 2):

Probably something to do with the regional settings of the machine that this is being run on, and the date format that is being ultimately passed into your insert statement being something along the lines of:

```
27/09/2012 4:17:42 PM
```

(being the current date here in Australia as I write this).

SQL Server may be trying to cast that into whatever date format it's using, and can't (e.g. thinks the first parameter is the month, but 27 is greater than 12).

Try formatting the dates in `YYYY-MM-DD` format:

```
2012-09-27
```

Or better yet, use parameters instead, as you have an SQL Injection vulnerability there.

Comment: Sure, but what happens if you send them as requestedD.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")?  The error that you are getting is saying that SQL Server tried to convert your string to a date, but the resultant date was out of range.  I believe this will solve the issue.

Comment: ok it checked it...it seems as though only one column is caausing this error...the rest of date columns are recieving data

Comment: That can still be a date conversion issue.  I still think that formatting as yyyy-MM-dd OR using parameters is the way to go.

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd` can still be ambiguous in some circumstances. `yyyyMMdd` is safer, and not subject to regional issues.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever curious to know how so?

Comment: @BrendanGreen - I know I've seen the dashed version interpreted as `yyyy-dd-MM` in some scenarios. Just trying to get a repro working now.

Comment: `set language british; select DATEPART(month,CONVERT(datetime,'2012-05-03'))` produces the result `3`, not `5`. (You can omit the `CONVERT()` step on SQL Server 2005 or earlier)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever well, never seen that before.  Thanks for taking the time to demonstrate.  Will have to keep that in mind.

Comment: you're right...it is the syntax...i gotta format the dates to MM-DD-YYYY format